# Recursive search in REDIS

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, etcd, redis-cluster

In ETCD, Say following are the key-value pairs:

company/google/employees/employee1
employeeID1

company/google/employees/employee2
employeeID2

company/amazon/employees/employee1
employeeID1

company/amazon/employees/employee2
employeeID2

When I do a Fetch on "company/amazon/", I get the employee IDs of all employees in amazon (and the same applies for "company/google/") and a fetch on "company/" fetches all the employee IDs.
Is this supported in REDIS ? If not, how can we do the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by using a hash and [HSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) to pattern-match the key.

One hash with all your data encapsulates the scan to only the relevant keys, and not all keys on the database.

And `HSCAN` has the advantage it returns the key and the value. `KEYS` and `SCAN` only return the keys and then you need to fetch values.

```
> HSET myData company/google/employees/employee1 employeeID1
(integer) 1
> HSET myData company/google/employees/employee2 employeeID2
(integer) 1
> HSET myData company/amazon/employees/employee1 employeeID1
(integer) 1
> HSET myData company/amazon/employees/employee2 employeeID2
(integer) 1
> HSCAN myData 0 MATCH company/amazon/* COUNT 100
1) "0"
2) 1) "company/amazon/employees/employee1"
   2) "employeeID1"
   3) "company/amazon/employees/employee2"
   4) "employeeID2"
> HSCAN myData 0 MATCH company/google/* COUNT 100
1) "0"
2) 1) "company/google/employees/employee1"
   2) "employeeID1"
   3) "company/google/employees/employee2"
   4) "employeeID2"
> HSCAN myData 0 MATCH company/* COUNT 100
1) "0"
2) 1) "company/google/employees/employee1"
   2) "employeeID1"
   3) "company/google/employees/employee2"
   4) "employeeID2"
   5) "company/amazon/employees/employee1"
   6) "employeeID1"
   7) "company/amazon/employees/employee2"
   8) "employeeID2"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Instead of passing any integer for count, Is there any way, I can  get all the fields and values, or say count is "all"

Comment: If you omit count, it will use 10. Max value is 9223372036854775807, but use with care. The goal of scan is precisely to avoid blocking the server for long time. You are supposed to use a decent number, and use the returned cursor to continue the scan.